# Creating a weight adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, graph

I need to assign weights to edges of a graph, from the following papers:

"Fast linear iterations for distributed averaging" by L. Xiao and S. Boyd
"Convex Optimization of Graph Laplacian Eigenvalues" by S. Boyd

I have the adjacency matrix for my graph (a 50 by 50 matrix), with 512 non-zero values.

I also have a 256 by 1 vector with the optimal weights.

For the software I'm using, I need a 50 by 50 matrix with the weight of edge (i,j) in the relevant position of the adjacency matrix (and with the opposite sign for edge (j,i)).

My attempt is below, but I can't get it working.

```
function weights = construct_weight_mtx(weight_list, Adj)

weights = zeros(size(Adj));
positions = find(Adj);

for i=1:length(positions)/2
    if Adj(i) == 1
        weights(i) = weight_list(i);
    end
end

weights = weights - weights';

find(Adj) == find(weights);

end
```

Comment: You've got a couple of problems, and I can figure out most of them, but why are you subtracting `weights - weights'`? Do you actually want the weight in one direction to be the negative of the weight in the opposite direction?

Comment: @beaker yes - I do want the weights to be negative in the opposite direction.

Comment: lol... you actually said that in the description... my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're finding the nonzero positions in the original adjacency matrix, but you're finding *all* of them. To get around this, you then take only the first half of those positions.

```
for i=1:length(positions)/2 ...
```

Unfortunately, this takes the indices from complete columns rather than just the positions below the diagonal. So if your matrix was all 1's, you'd be taking:

```
1 1 1 0 0 ...
1 1 1 0 0 ...
1 1 1 0 0 ...
...
```

instead of:

```
1 0 0 0 0 ...
1 1 0 0 0 ...
1 1 1 0 0 ...
...
```

To take the correct values, we just take the lower triangular portion of `Adj` and then find the nonzero positions of that:

```
positions = find(tril(Adj));
```

Now we have only the 256 positions below the diagonal and we can loop over all of the positions. Next, we need to fix the assignment in the loop:

```
for i=1:length(positions)
    if Adj(i) == 1   %// we already know Adj(i) == 1 for all indices in positions
        weights(i) = weight_list(i);   %// we need to update weights(positions(i))
    end
end
```

So this becomes:

```
for i=1:length(positions)
    weights(positions(i)) = weight_list(i);
end
```

But if all we're doing is assigning 256 values to 256 positions, we can do that without a `for` loop:

```
weights(position) = weight_list;
```

Note that the elements of `weight_list` must be in the proper order with the nonzero elements of the lower-triangular portion ordered by columns.

---

Completed code:

```
function weights = construct_weight_mtx(weight_list, Adj)

weights = zeros(size(Adj));
positions = find(tril(Adj));

weights(positions) = weight_list;

weights = weights - weights.';   %// ' is complex conjugate; not a big deal here, but something to know

find(Adj) == find(weights);   %// Not sure what this is meant to do; maybe an assert?

end
```