# How to add weighting factors into adjacency matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have adjacency matrix (936x936) abstracted from a graph with 936 nodes and 1274 pipes. So
I want to create a weight adjacency matrix which associated with various factors at pipes and nodes such as (Length, Diameter of that pipes and Elevation, Pressure at that nodes)

I already tried by this following code but something wrong due to matrix dimensions. Someone could please help me to solve this

```
function [weighted_length] = CreateWeightLengthMatrix(Length, adj)
weighted_length = zeros(size(adj));
positions = find(tril(adj));

weighted_length(positions) = Length;

weighted_length = abs(weighted_length - weighted_length.');

find(adj) == find(weighted_length);

end
```

I also changed this code by the simple code below, but I got the same problem. Could you help me please?

```
function [weighted_length] = CreateWeightLengthMatrix(Length, adj)

weighted_length = zeros(size(adj));
positions = find(adj);

for i=1:length(positions)/2
    if adj(i)==1
        weighted_length(positions(i)) = Length(i);
    end
end

weighted_length = weighted_length - weighted_length';

find(adj) == find(weighted_length);

end
```

Comment: Which line do you hat the dimension problem?

Comment: what is the dimension of Length?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the first algorithms, dimension problem cause by this line. "weighted_length(positions) = Length;"

Comment: Did you check the dimensions of `weighted_length` and `Length`? I have no further information from you post but you can do the check by yourself. Otherwise, could you provide a toy example with fake data for your problem?

Comment: Actually, I followed the code for adding weight factors from previous post as the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406965/creating-a-weight-adjacency-matrix. However, in my case, dimension of adjacency matrix and weight matrix different. In particular, Adjacency matrix is (936x936) because network have 936 nodes. And weighting matrix is (1x1274) because have 1274 pipes connected with these nodes. My mission is how to add weight factors from weighting matrix into adjacency matrix. Do you clearly understand my problems and could please help me?

Comment: What is the dimension of `Length`? I just want to know the dimensions of it that you are using in `weighted_length(positions) = Length`. Also, please @ me when you reply, otherwise I have no idea you are replying to whom

Comment: @ADinaka Seriously, i think you have problems to understand what you're actually trying to do rather than how to implement it. What is the correlation between the Adjacency matrix and the weighting matrix, since they've got differently dimensions?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, Length is the matrix of weighting factor Length = (1274x1), while adj = (936 x 936)

Comment: Does `positions` also contain 1274 or more elements?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. The positions is lower (exactly is 1269 elements),dear

Comment: Then I don't think you are able to use the assignment expression `weighted_length(positions) = Length` since `positions` and `Length` does not have the same number of elements.....

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding. Do you have any ideas for solving that problem?

Comment: @ADinaka I don't think you can solve it unless you can ensure `positions` and `Length` have the same number of elements.